# How to get a value from wunderground .json

Tags: php, arrays, json, wunderground

I'm working on json source from wunderground.com. As the example code displayed in the document. I can adjust and work out for some simple format. But I'm stuck with this one. I tried to googled every where but there's no solution.

Here's the sample codes:

```
<?php
  $json_string = file_get_contents("http://api.wunderground.com/api/b8e924a8f008b81e/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json");
  $parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
  $location = $parsed_json->{'location'}->{'city'};
  $temp_f = $parsed_json->{'current_observation'}->{'temp_f'};
  echo "Current temperature in ${location} is: ${temp_f}\n";
?>
```

Well, I need some information like "**Cedar Rapids**" out of **pws/station** :

```
"pws": {
        "station": [
        {
        "neighborhood":"Ellis Park Time Check",
        "city":"Cedar Rapids",
        "state":"IA",
        "country":"US",
        "id":"KIACEDAR22",
        "lat":41.981174,
        "lon":-91.682632,
        "distance_km":2,
        "distance_mi":1
        }
]
}
```

(You can get all code by clicking this : http://api.wunderground.com/api/b8e924a8f008b81e/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json )
Now the questions are:

1. What is this data called? (array, array in array?)
2. How could I pull this data out of the line?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`station` is an array within the `pws` object.

To get the data, you can do something like this:

```
<?php
  $json_string = file_get_contents("http://api.wunderground.com/api/b8e924a8f008b81e/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json");
  $parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
  $location = $parsed_json->{'location'}->{'city'};
  $temp_f = $parsed_json->{'current_observation'}->{'temp_f'};
  echo "Current temperature in ${location} is: ${temp_f}\n";

  $stations = $parsed_json->{'location'}->{'nearby_weather_stations'}->{'pws'}->{'station'};
  $count = count($stations);
  for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
  {
     $station = $stations[$i];
     if (strcmp($station->{'id'}, "KIACEDAR22") == 0)
     {
        echo "Neighborhood: " . $station->{'neighborhood'} . "\n";
        echo "City: " . $station->{'city'} . "\n";
        echo "State: " . $station->{'state'} . "\n";
        echo "Latitude: " . $station->{'lat'} . "\n";
        echo "Longitude: " . $station->{'lon'} . "\n";
        break;
     }
  }
?>
```

Output:

```
Current temperature in Cedar Rapids is: 38.5
Neighborhood: Ellis Park Time Check
City: Cedar Rapids
State: IA
Latitude: 41.981174
Longitude: -91.682632
```